# Best Key-Value database for intensive insertion

Tags: database, data, go, key-value-store

We are working on a project of type (intensive insertion) should able to handle millions of insertion per day.

**The Current situation**

- we have two table one of them includes 2 billion record (Id & meta data) and another one includes 30 million record (Id & meta data).
- the total storage is 600 GB.
- we are using PostgreSQL on one node (32G RAM, 24 Core, 2TB Storage).

**The Issue now is PostgreSQL is not able to handle all this insertion** so we tried to shard the tables to 1000-sub-tables and handle the insertion from the backend-service. but this solution is not stable and hard to maintain.

**Now we are looking for simple key-value storage able to handle intensive insertion** Also we are using **Golang**. so the database required to have Golang connector

what we did find :

- **Redis** : very fast database, but required the data to be able to fit in memory
- **rocksdb & leveldb** : both of them looks like they will work for the problem, but they don't have official Golang connector.

Comment: Have you tried BerkeleyDB?